# Import data from Excel File into a dataTable.DataTable return empty column

Tags: excel, import, datatable

i want to import excel to my database . But now i got a very weird problem while importing the data from excel file.

Here is the screen shoot for the excel file

[image]

I actually want to import the column of **Brand** into my database.I can import those record which are **AW08** to the dataTable , but when the record is **2006** , the datatable return me empty column.On the other hand the format of brand is **general** type

Here is the screen shoot of the dataTable

[image]

Here is my coding

```
 DataTable dtExcel = new DataTable();
            OleDbConnection conn = new OleDbConnection(strConn);
            // Initialize an OleDbDataAdapter object.

            conn.Open();
            OleDbCommand ocmd = new OleDbCommand("select * from [MenShoe $] ", conn);
            // Initialize an OleDbDataAdapter object.
            OleDbDataAdapter da = new OleDbDataAdapter("select * from [MenShoe $] ", conn);
            // Fill the DataTable with data from the Excel spreadsheet.
            da.Fill(dtExcel);
```

Does anyone face this problem before?

Answer (score 0):

Maybe your problem is related to the kind of formatting applied to the BRAND column.

See that `AW08` looks like a string and `2006` is treated like a number. Take a look at that.

Try to modify the formatting of the entire column in Excel to use TEXT instead and test the import again.

Comment: Hello, the format of entire column is **general**. I Try erase the 2006 and fill text in the column again. Then i change the column as **text**.Now it work .It is the format of general type is not inappropriate for number such as 2006?By the way got other better solution without manually change the record? because i may import large amount of data

Comment: @user998405: so as I expected changing the formatting did the trick. I'd recommend that you set the column format to TEXT (since it can hold any type of data and reflects your given situation). Save this Excel spreadsheet as a template and pass it to whoever uses it.